# EBS Multi-Volume Snapshots Completion Status cause

Tags: amazon-web-services, events, snapshot

how do I populate the cause field in the detail body of the event when creating snapshots?

This is the event:

```
{
  "version": "0",
  "id": "01234567-0123-0123-0123-012345678901",
  "detail-type": "EBS Multi-Volume Snapshots Completion Status",
  "source": "aws.ec2",
  "account": "123456789012",
  "time": "2018-07-16T17:29:36Z",
  "region": "us-east-1",
  "resources": ["arn:aws:ec2::us-east-1:snapshot/snap-01234567", "arn:aws:ec2::us-east-1:snapshot/snap-012345678"],
  "detail": {
    "event": "createSnapshots",
    "result": "succeeded",
    "cause": "",
    "request-id": "",
    "startTime": "2018-07-16T14:31:10Z",
    "endTime": "2018-07-16T17:28:16Z",
    "snapshots": [{
      "snapshot_id": "arn:aws:ec2::us-east-1:snapshot/snap-01234567",
      "source": "arn:aws:ec2::us-east-1:volume/vol-01234567",
      "status": "completed"
    }, {
      "snapshot_id": "arn:aws:ec2::us-east-1:snapshot/snap-012345678",
      "source": "arn:aws:ec2::us-east-1:volume/vol-012345678",
      "status": "completed"
    }]
  }
}
```

As you can see the cause is as `"cause": "",`. My question is how do I populate the cause? Where can I specify it during the snapshot creation?

Comment: This gets populated when your operation is unsuccessful. E.g, when your snapshot is failed, this will get populated with the cause of the failure.

Answer (score 0):

This gets populated when your operation is unsuccessful. E.g, when your snapshot is failed, this will get populated with the cause of the failure